# Using rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with the Salesforce Ruby API which has a pretty good, but slightly dated set up guide. After installing the right gems it says to enter 'script/console' into the command line, and then enter '>> Salesforce::Contact.first' which should respond with a user id.

I have read other's post saying that script/console is no longer being used and to use rails console instead. That works fine, but when I enter '>> Salesforce::Contact.first' it complains that the syntax is wrong.

I also tried removing the >> from the front and it resulted in it saying "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

I there some other command besides '>> Salesforce::Contact.first' that I should be using?

Thanks

Comment: try `require 'Salesforce'` to load the API into the console.

Comment: If the guide shows `>>` in front of all their commands, I'm guessing it is supposed to represent the prompt in the Rails console, so it should not be entered. The error message you wrote makes me think you tried to execute that line from the command line, but not in the Rails console itself. Make sure you're in the console first - make sure you've done `rails console` first, and then `Salesforce::Contact.first` second.

Comment: When I enter rails console it responds with 
"Usage: 
   rails new APP_PATH [option]

Options:
..."
And then a whole list of different options. But it doesn't seem like the Rails console actually comes up. (I have never used the rails console before so I am not sure what to look for)

Comment: You have to be inside a Rails application's directory before you can use the console. If you haven't started your project, do that first. If you have started your project, `cd` into it.

Comment: When I cd into my project and enter rails c, it says rails is not recognized as a command

Comment: once you were in the correct directory did you try using script/console when rails console didn't work?

Comment: Yeah, I tried bother and neither one worked. No commands seem to work unless I am in my Ruby193/bin folder. If I go any deeper the commands aren't recognized. Is that normal? Am I supposed to call everything from the bin folder and just enter the path each time?

Comment: @user3735405 In regards to the directory issue, you're referring to the [question you asked earlier this morning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24207709/877472), but you haven't replied to any of the comments. Have you checked it out recently?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that people had commented on my other post

Answer (score 1):

`>>` (and similar things) represent the prompt that you should see already on the screen for you. It's essentially the console saying "Go ahead, type something"

Try to 'mentally' strip stuff like that off from the beginning, including spaces. This would mean that the 'command' you're looking to execute is really,

`Salesforce::Contact.first`

Hope this helps.

Comment: `>>` is both the default `irb` prompt and the Ruby shift operator, so it generates syntax errors when used incorrectly.

Comment: Correct, I could understand the confusion, it takes a bit of intuition to be able to determine when code is calling to use a Bitwise Shift or just a prompt.